# Batch script to replace special characters with correct characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, character

i have a problem with replacing a (dos  encoding characters ?) with the correct characters .

I need to  replace it in a txt file log, with batch windows or similar.

I need to replace

·
Þ

etc (...)

with the correct characters

Á
À
Â
Å
Ã
Ä
É
È
Ê
Ë
Í
Ì
Î
Ï
Ñ
Ó
Ò
Ô
Õ
Ö
Ú
Ù
Û
Ü

Best  Regards

Comment: Fine. And what is your question? Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: what about iconv? there should be windows equivalent as well

Comment: Why do you think that _any_ character in a txt file might be incorrect?

Comment: Þ doesn't appear in US console, only in Western Europe console as code 222 (and in Western ANSI). So what encoding is your file and what encoding do you want.

Comment: Use a text editor like UltraEdit which has the command __OEM to ANSI__ to convert an OEM encoded text file to ANSI encoded text file. There is absolutely no need to code this character conversion with a batch file in my point of view although it would be possible depending on log file size. I suppose you are from Italy or Switzerland or another Western European Country and therefore in console windows [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) is used and you need to convert the log file to [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).